# Using Websocket for chatting application

Tags: websocket, apollo-client, server-sent-events

For making a chat application, the standard recommendation seems to be to use Websocket to receive live data from the server, and it appears that that's what most people do. But what I don't understand is **why production chat apps send messages to the server through a standard AJAX request, instead of using WS**.

Both Discord and Slack's browser application, despite them maintaining WS connections, the apps just send POST to one of its endpoints when sending a chat message.

Not production chat app, but ApolloClient's `useSubscription` uses WS to receive events from the server, but mutate (which is what we would use to send messages) sent as a standard AJAX.

For a chatting application, if we have a dedicated WS connection with a server, wouldn't it be faster/more efficient to use that for sending any data? I assume there's a valid reason why sending data (chat message for a chatting app) is done through a standard AJAX, but then wouldnt SSE be a better/less resource-intensive option over WS?

Comment: However this question is overly broad for Stack Overflow’s Q&A format - we can’t possibly answer this question as you’ve posed it without inside knowledge into the software design process at these providers - even then, this information is likely covered as trade secret or under NDA and can’t be disclosed here by anyone with any pertinent knowledge. Voting to close

Comment: But EvenSource is suppored by 97%... also, Discord uses WS for Server->Client, but AJAX for sending a text message from Client->Server, so browsers that don't have WS support, and cant be polyfilled wouldnt be able to use Discord, no?

Comment: did you delete your first comment because you realized how off-topic it was? Can you just unflag my post? I really think this is a legit question that doesnt violate any community guidelines

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> wouldn't SSE be a better/less resource-intensive option over WS?

Both Server Sent Events and Web Sockets have a very similar implementation: they hold open a *dedicated* socket between the client and the server. So, to answer your last question first: they have the same use of the critical resources (sockets, and server memory for that process).

> why sending data (chat message for a chatting app) is done through a standard AJAX

AJAX opens the socket (*), sends the data, the server process handles it (pushing it to another server or writing to a database), and then the socket can be closed, and the server has capacity to handle the next incoming request.

*: With HTTP/2 multiplexing, there may already be a socket ready most of the time.

A single server that could handle 1000 clients of AJAX pushing could perhaps only handle 50-100 SSE or web socket connections at any one time. The ratio depends on the nature of the chat messages and the acceptable latency.

At one extreme, if you want to post each keypress as it happens, and have everyone get sent that character, and most people are typing most of the time, the AJAX approach might also only be able to handle 50-100 clients at a time.

At the other extreme, if the chat are full sentences, and not sent off until the user presses Enter, and each client only writes a comment once every few minutes, then the single server might be able to handle 10,000 of those kind of clients.

> despite them maintaining WS connections, the apps just send POST to one of its endpoints when sending a chat message.

This is the curious bit, isn't it: in an ideal world, you'd re-use that connection. I think it will come down to practical engineering issues. Different departments handling different servers, with different scalability and latency requirements, and possibly different security and backup policies.

In other words, if receiving the messages, pushing them into the database, polling for new messages, and sending them out, is all handled by the single process holding open that dedicated socket, then all that code needs to be in one large, heavy, hard to maintain piece of software. It still sounds quite simple, 10 lines of code? But by the time they are enterprise-ready, with authentication, billing, legacy support, spam detection, etc, etc. they are thousands of lines.

The other thing to throw into the mix is that dedicated sockets are hard to maintain through proxies and on mobile. You need to be running an ajax version to give reliable service to those clients. So if you have to do it anyway, you might as well use it for everybody and save writing the code twice.